# assert every selected div element

Tags: css, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I want to test every selected div, but it only test the first select element.

This is DOM:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="select" [datetime="20190101"]>
                <div class="data">{{data}}</div>
                <div class="other"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="select" [datetime="20190102"]>
                <div class="data">{{data}}</div>
                <div class="other"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- and many of them -->
</div>
```

This is my testing:

```
/** @test */
public function every_data_should_match()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/page');

        $browser->whenAvailable('div.select', function ($div) {
            $datetime = $div->attribute('div.data', 'datetime');
            $expected_data = User::where('datetime', $datetime)->first()->data;

            $data = $div->getAttribute('outerHTML');

            $this->assertSame($expected_data, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

> There should have many assertions, but there is only one,
>   how to fix so the testing would iterate every div.select?

Each .select belongs to different parent, so I couldn't use .select:nth-child(n).

Comment: Apparently dusk doesn't really have a way to iterate through all selector matches. There was [an issue about it](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/126) which seems to have been closed without any explanation. There's a few workarounds mentioned in there.

Comment: Are all `<select>` element available at the same time?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, they show at the same time, and I have checked by dd(count($browser->elements('div.select')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `elements()`:

```php
/** @test */
public function every_data_should_match()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/page');

        $browser->waitFor('div.select');

        foreach ($browser->elements('div.select') as $select) {
            $datetime = $select->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('div.data'))->getAttribute('datetime');
            $expected_data = User::where('datetime', $datetime)->first()->data;

            $data = $select->getAttribute('outerHTML');

            $this->assertSame($expected_data, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```$browser->elements()``` return an ```RemoteWebElement``` object, it fails to call ```->attribute()```

Comment: I replaced that with `getAttribute()` in my answer.

Comment: I modified my question, and add a selector inside ```->attribute()```

Comment: How to use ```getAttribute()``` if there is a selector when using ```->attribute('selector', 'datetime')```?